# ASP .Net C#: Get Binaries from fileupoad to generate XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, pdf, base64

I am currently at the end of my program but am coming into a section that I have NO experience in. I've been able to convert the PDF to a Base64 in other methods but those are not permitted as per the instructions I've been given. I've posted my code below in the hopes that someone can maybe get me started in the right direction. I do not have any clue how to put in the volumes either so ANY assistance would be awesome! Contained is the Get Binaries and the IO class which it reads.

**Default.cs.aspx**

```
private static List<Binary> GetBinaries()
{
    return new List<Binary>
    { 
        new Binary
        {
            //hardcoded but need to call from fileUpload1
            BinaryBase64Object = IO.ReadFromFile(@"..\..\EFACTS eRecord Technical Specification.pdf"), **<-- How do I get this to read from fileupload1**
            BinaryID = "BIN1234", //hardcoded
            BinarySizeValue = 56443, //hardcoded
            FileName = " test.my.pdf", //hardcoded
            PageRange = "23-89", //hardcoded
            NoOfPages = 14, //hardcoded
            TotalVolumes = 1, //hardcoded
            Volume = 1 //hardcoded
        }
    };
}
```

**IO.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Electronic_Filing_of_Appeals;

namespace Electronic_Filing_of_Appeals
{

    public static class IO
    {

        public static void ReadWriteStream(MemoryStream readStream, Stream writeStream)
        {

            using (writeStream)
            {
                int Length = 256;
                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];

                readStream.Position = 0;
                int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);

                // write the required bytes
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                }

                readStream.Close();
                writeStream.Close();
            }
        }

        public static MemoryStream FileToMemoryStream(string filename)
        {
            FileStream inStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename);
            MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();

            outStream.SetLength(inStream.Length);
            inStream.Read(outStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)inStream.Length);

            outStream.Flush();
            inStream.Close();

            return outStream;
        }

        public static MemoryStream ConvertStreamToMemoryStream(Stream stream)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            if (stream != null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = stream.ReadFully();
                if (buffer != null)
                {
                    var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
                    binaryWriter.Write(buffer);
                }
            }
            return memoryStream;
        }

        public static byte[] ReadFromFile(string filePath)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] fileRD = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            br.Close();
            fs.Close();
            return fileRD;
        }

        public static void SaveToFile(byte[] byteData, string fileName)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }

        public static byte[] ReadFully(this Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for some more assistance. There are probably some library for reading PDF-files already in use. Try to find out what it is, and read the code to see how it is used.

If this is the first time in the project anyone had to read PDF-files, you will have to adopt some library. Writing one on your own is very time-consuming. What you are looking for is a library that can read the meta-data from the PDF.

Two such libraries are [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) and [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/). Here are an example with PDFSharp:

```
var doc = PdfReader.Open(@"icpc_briefing_1_sep_10.pdf");
Console.WriteLine("Number of pages: {0}", doc.PageCount);

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("=== INFO ===");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PdfItem> pair in doc.Info)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}

byte[] xmlData = GetMetadata(doc);
if (xmlData != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("=== XMP ===");
    Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xmlData));
    Console.WriteLine();
}

byte[] GetMetadata(PdfDocument doc)
{
    // PdfSharp does not have direct support for the XML metadata, but it does
    // allow you to go poking into the internal structure.
    PdfItem metadataItem;
    if (doc.Internals.Catalog.Elements.TryGetValue("/Metadata", out metadataItem))
    {
        var metadataRef = (PdfReference) metadataItem;
        var metadata = (PdfDictionary) metadataRef.Value;
        return metadata.Stream.Value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Example output:**

```xml
Number of pages: 27

=== INFO ===
/CreationDate: D:20100910191635+08'00'
/Author: Steven Halim
/Creator: PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2
/Producer: Acrobat Distiller 8.1.0 (Windows)
/ModDate: D:20130610173442+02'00'
/Title: Microsoft PowerPoint - icpc_briefing_1_sep_10 [Compatibility Mode]

=== XMP ===
<?xpacket begin="?" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 4.0-c316 44.253921, Sun Oct 01 2006 17:14:39">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xap="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
         <xap:CreatorTool>PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2</xap:CreatorTool>
         <xap:ModifyDate>2010-09-10T19:16:35+08:00</xap:ModifyDate>
         <xap:CreateDate>2010-09-10T19:16:35+08:00</xap:CreateDate>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
         <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
         <dc:title>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Microsoft PowerPoint - icpc_briefing_1_sep_10 [Compatibility Mode]</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </dc:title>
         <dc:creator>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>Steven Halim</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:creator>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
         <pdf:Producer>Acrobat Distiller 8.1.0 (Windows)</pdf:Producer>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xapMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
         <xapMM:DocumentID>uuid:b5ffc85b-6578-48fb-bddf-a5215ffa9d35</xapMM:DocumentID>
         <xapMM:InstanceID>uuid:f45826a4-8c58-4a54-bac1-7f3192866d57</xapMM:InstanceID>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end="w"?>
```

Here are some more examples: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx

---

To get the data from a `<asp:FileUpload>` control, you just need to access [`FileUpload.FileBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes.aspx) (`byte[]`) or [`FileUpload.FileContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx) (`Stream`). Alternatively, you can access [`FileUpload.PostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile.aspx) or [`Request.Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx) for more information.

```
var doc = PdfReader.Open(FileUpload1.FileContent);
```

Comment: Basically, I believe this is what they are looking for. I will find out more details tomorrow from my boss.

Comment: You are correct. One of my counterparts in a different location is using PDFSharp for this process. I have NO clue in how to even get this process started. One of my issues is calling my fileupload from the cs.aspx and using that in the Get Binaries section.

Comment: @RaymondBeyrle I modified the code to use PDFSharp instead of iTextSharp.

Comment: You are awesome Markus!!! I will try my best to implement this into my program. I've never done anything this technical so it does pose as a challenge. Thanks again! Side question: do you think PDFSharp is better then iTextSharp? Just curious is all.

Comment: BinaryBase64Object = IO.ReadFromFile(@"..\..\EFACTS eRecord eRecord Technical Specification.pdf"), **<-- How do I get this to read from fileupload1**. This needs to be resolved before I get to move on to the paging portion. :( I have the string already in a hidden label but cannot get the other class to accept it. I've tried everything I know.